# Unable to install AzureAd module using Install-Module -Name AzureAD in ADO pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to execute Get-AzureADServicePrincipal in a azure powershell task in ADO.
I need to get service principal for me to then connect to get ServicePrincipalId and ServicePrincipalkey.
As part of this I am trying the below, as an inline script

Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal

But this keeps failing as,

WARNING: User declined to install module (AzureAD)

### [error]The term 'Get-AzureADServicePrincipal' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Please could some one help? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Install-Module` is prompting for user input. Specify the `-Force` flag.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using host agent. Better to install a module only for the **current user**

This example downloads and installs the newest version of a module, only for the current user. Also add `-Force`

```
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

**Then you need to call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets**.

Finally `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`.